# Use of extern: getting 'file not found'

Tags: c

//fpoin1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fpoin.c>
void swap(int,int);
void main()
{
int i=0;
i++;
if(i<=5)
{
printf("%d",i);
swap(59,23);
getch();
}
```

//fpoin.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
extern int i;
void swap(int ,int );
int main()
{
int i=3;
int p,q; 
swap(p,q);
printf("\np=%dq=%d",p,q);
getch(); 
return 0;    
}
void swap(int p,int q)
{
int t=p;
p=q;
q=t;
}
```

When I compile fpoin1, it says "fpoin.c not found", but both are in same directory.
What is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
#include "fpoin.c"
```

Using `""` or `<>` affects how the compiler searches for a file/header. You should use `<>` for "system" and "library" includes, and use `""` when including your own files.

But, you shouldn't include a `.c` file. You should compile each of these, then link them together, using e.g. this gcc one-liner: `gcc -Wall -o appname fpoin.c fpoin1.c`

You will also need to decide which of your two `main()` functions you want to use. You must have exactly one `main()`

Additionally, your `swap` function will not work as you expect, since you pass its arguments by value. Try this:

```
void swap(int * p, int * q) {
  int t=*p;
  *p=*q;
  *q=t;
}

...

swap(&p, &q)
```

Of course, you cannot then call `swap(59,23)` - There's no variables to modify. What was `swap(59,23)` supposed to do?

Comment: yeah i forgot i messed up with my two different files.thanks i have fixed that two main problem removing one.

Answer (score 2):

One normally only includes *.h* files, and *links* other *.c* files, but if you are going to include a local file, it should be done with `"..."` and not `<...>` delimiters, so:

```
#include "fpoin.c"
```

The `<...>` indicates a system header.

In your case, just switching to linking won't quite be good enough, as your `main()` will be multiply-defined either way. You might want to rethink your modularization a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Using `<` and `>` in the `#include` says to the compiler that you are including a "standard header". Standard headers need not be real files on your disk: **the compiler uses magic to include standard headers**.

To include real files, use quotes in the `#include` line

```
#include "fpoin.c"
```

One more thing: don't get used to including code. Write files with declarations only and include them (tipically files with `.h` extension).